# Does a wire cut at a place work as a Capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance

Suppose we have a electric wire with a battery connected to the two terminals of the wire. If we cut the wire at a place and separate the two terminals (having small cross sectional area) at a very small distance, **will the circuit work as a Capacitor now ?**

Comment: A wire has self capacitance. A cable (wire in a sheath) even more obviously. See, for example, the cable pulser.

Answer (score 3):

Technically yes, but even if you place the ends of the wires close together and separate them with a [dielectric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric) the capacitance will be very, very small because of the small cross-sectional area of the wire.

A rough estimate suggests that the capacitance between the two ends of a cut wire would be less than one tenth of a picoFarad. According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farad):

> Capacitance values of 1 pF or lower can be achieved by twisting two short lengths of insulated wire together.

Comment: Interesting and related. Wires running parallel in the wall can led to capacitor effect. If in the dark you seem to see your modern bulb flashing a bit believe your eyes, it is that.